# Vue 3 Dynamic import files

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build Vue 3 dynamic loading JSON files, in order to create a website builder. So each page is defined as a JSON file, in order to allow the user to change the JSON file from the backend (all components are defined in that file).

When I'm loading every other route than auth, it's working fine, but Auth is loading twice (the load_components function).

Here is the example of the routes. Most of the pages will have a loadParent component, but there are a few that will not. And loadParent for now has only `<router-view />` in it:

```
    // Simple page
    {
        path: "/home",
        name: "home",
        component: () => import("../loadPage.vue"),
    },
    // Pages with parent
    {
        name: 'auth',
        path: '/auth',
        meta: {
            title: "Some users" ,
            adminOnly: true
        },
        component: () => import("../loadParent.vue"),
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                name: 'login',
                props: (route: any) => ({}),
                component: () => import("../loadPage.vue"),
            }
        ]
    }
```

So here is how template looks like:

```
<template>
    <component v-for="block in components" :is="{...block.component}" :key="Math.random()" :vars="block.props"></component>
</template>
```

And in the setup script I have defined ref where is stored path of the file, like:

```
const json: any = ref();
```

Because every file is defined as route name, I'm using import in setup:

```
json.value = import('../pages/' + route.value + '.json');
```

So here is how the function how I'm actually loading the components:

```
const load_components = async () => {
        console.log('load page components ')
        // Get file for load
        Promise.resolve(json.value).then(function (e: any) {
            // Reset previous page pages
            components.value = [];

            // For each component for the page and register them under new const of the pages
            e.default.components.forEach((c: any) => {
                components.value.push({
                    "component": defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./templates/' + template.value + '/' + c.component)),
                    "props": c.props
                })
            })
        }).catch((e: any) => {
            // If component can't be loaded - Delete for production
            console.log(e + ' cannot be loaded!');
        });
    }
```

So in order to trigger the function, I'm doing something like:

```
onBeforeMount(async() => {
            json.value = import('../pages/' + route.value + '.json');

            // Initiate component load
            await load_components()
        })

        // /** Watch when client changes a page to load new json for next page - This function is for pages that has same component */
        watch(router, async (value: any) => {
            json.value = import('../pages/' + value.name + '.json');

            // There is no need for that if I load it really dynamically
            await load_components()
        })
```

Maybe just the approach is not correct, what do you think?